# How to use LIKE in meta_query()

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason, my LIKE parameter doesnt seem to work. If i use = instead, this query works.

Array:

```
$ref_query = array(       
  'meta_key' => 'reference_code',
  'value' => array($ref),
  'compare' => 'LIKE'       
);
```

This small array is apart of several other arrays which are pushed into the following line:

```
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query);
```

All other arrays work fine including their operators (>= , <= etc).

EDIT: It appears this does work however my results were being ordered by the post ID where as I was looking to have the result from the query return first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `meta_compare` instead.

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):

> meta_compare (string) - Operator to test the 'meta_value'. Possible values are '=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'NOT EXISTS', 'REGEXP', 'NOT REGEXP' or 'RLIKE'. Default value is '='.

Example from the documentation:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'color',
    'meta_value'   => 'blue',
    'meta_compare' => '!='
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use compare for like only search text but if you want use array we need foreach it and relation in meta_query.

Code demo:

```
$meta_query[0] = array('relation' => 'OR');
$all_meta = array('type','Brand','companyname','contactperson','phone','website','openinghours','coffeemachine'/*,'map_location'*/,'map-address1','map-address2','map-address3','map-zip','map-state','map-city','price');
foreach ($all_meta as $meta) {
    $meta_query[0][] = array(
        'key'     => $meta,
        'value'   => $custom_key,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    }
```

Comment: Not all the arrays are always submitted from the form thus each is contained in an if statement. In addition, other arrays use BETWEEN for compare.